# Error copying files to a folder more than 25,000

Tags: android, file, download, filesystems, fat32

Trying to copy the files to a folder on **sdcard**, all copied normally until the number of files in the folder is not close to 25,000 and then throws an error copying:

> Failed to copy file

- I Tried to copy different files (think the problem in which some of the files)
- Tried to copy different file managers on android - the exact same error
- Connect the tablet to a PC via USB, trying to copy - the exact same error
- Created on **sdcard** another folder and began to copy the files to it again, the result is the same. Those. Now I have two folders with a totally different files with the approximate number of files in each of about 25,000 and an error copying
- Alternative solutions to break through folders - **not suitable**

How to solve this issue?

```
 The number of files in a folder: 25,000
 The total size of the files in the folder: 4.5 GB
 Device: Lenovo IdeaTab A3000-H
 Android: 4.2.2
 sdcard: 16 GB FAT32
```